# OpenWrt Factory VLAN settings, no action needed?

Tags: networking, router, openwrt, vlan

After reading the [OpenWrt VLAN wiki](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/vlan/switch_configuration), I still don't have a clue what these VLANs in my router do?

Here is what I have from the start I believe, so this should be Factory VLAN settings:

[image: Factory VLAN settings]

---

The question is, should I better not touch it = it's ok for a general home setup?

Or should I change it somehow, for example, disable VLANs? What would happen then?

Comment: *For any data to cross the WAN and LAN border, it has to pass the CPU on eth0 (where the router and firewall will be filtering the data). As said above, nothing prevents to make VLANs that bypass the CPU entirely.* I.e. you may disable VLAN if you do not need in it really. If you don't want to disable VLAN but want to kommutate packets directly touch WAN to VLAN vlanid=1 instead VLAN vlanid=2, apply, then untouch both CPU interfaces from VLANs. And VLAN vlanid=2 can be removed in such case because of no interfaces attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OpenWrt has a forum which has addressed [this](https://forum.openwrt.org/search?q=vLAN).*

A [**v**[irtual] **LAN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN) is a software-based network that can apply to physical hardware switches or virtual adapters which are not attached to any physical hardware.

OpenWrt utilizies vLANs by default, as it allows for greater flexibility and simplicity for users.

- There is no reason to touch the default configuration unless:

  - Creating a WAN bridge with some of the LAN ports, allowing two or more internet connections to be made to the router
  - Configuring two or more subnets, where at least one of them will be assigned to one or more of LAN ports 1 - 4

LuCI's vLAN page can over-complicate vLAN setup, with the network config showing it more simply:

- **`/etc/config/network`**

  ```ini
  #===========================================================
                ##----- Virtual Switches -----##
  #===========================================================

      # vSwitches #
  #-----------------------------------------------------------

  # Switch 0:
  config switch
      option  name            'switch0'
      option  enable_vlan     1
      option  reset           1

      # vLANs #
  #-----------------------------------------------------------

  # 1: LAN
  config switch_vlan
      option  device          'switch0'
      option  ports           '0 1 2 3 5t'
      option  vlan            1

  # 2: WAN
  config switch_vlan
      option  device          'switch0'
      option  ports           '4 6t'
      option  vlan            2
  ```

  - **`Switch0`:** vLAN Switch, consisting of CPU ports `eth0` & `eth1`

    - **`eth0.1`:** Network interface for CPU port `eth0` &  LAN ports 1 - 4

      - *LAN ports 1-4 are identified by OpenWrt as `sw.port0` [LAN4] - `sw.port3` [LAN1]*
    - **`eth1.2`:** Network interface for CPU port `eth1` and WAN port

      - *WAN port is identified by OpenWrt as `sw.port4`*

      ```ini
      #===========================================================
                           ##----- Networks ----##
      #===========================================================

      # LAN #
      #-----------------------------------------------------------
      config interface 'lan'
           option  ifname          'eth0.1'
           option  type            'bridge'
           option  proto           'static'
           option  broadcast       192.168.1.1
           option  ipaddr          192.168.1.1
           option  netmask         255.255.255.0

      # WAN #
      #-----------------------------------------------------------
      config interface 'wan'
           option  ifname          'eth1.2'
           option  proto           'dhcp'

      config interface 'wan6'
           option  ifname          'eth1.2'
           option  proto           'dhcpv6'
      ```